# Grouping or Clustering Algorithm

Tags: set, grouping, cluster-analysis, similarity, difference

Similar questions in the database seem to be much more complicated than my example. I want to cluster 100'ish points on a line. Number of groups is irrelevant; the closeness of points is more important.

What is a term, method or algorithm to deal with this grouping problem? K-means, Hamming distance, hierarchical agglomeration, clique or complete linkage??

I've reduced two examples to bare minimum for clarification:

Simple example:
Set A = {600, 610, 620, 630} and the set of differences between its elements is diff_A = {10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 10}. I can then group as follows: {10, 10, 10}, {20, 20}, and {30}. Done.

Problematic example:
Set B = {600, 609, 619, 630} and the set of differences is diff_B = {9, 10, 11, 19, 21, 30}. I try to group with a tolerance of 1, i.e. differences that are 1 (or less) are 'similar enough' to be grouped but I get a paradox: {9, 10} AND/OR {10, 11}, {19}, {21}, and {30}.

Issue:
9 and 10 are close enough, 10 and 11 are close enough, but 9 and 11 are not, so how should I handle these overlapping groups? Perhaps this small example is unsolvable because it is symmetrical?

Comment: possible duplicate of [partitioning an float array into similar segments (clustering)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479944/partitioning-an-float-array-into-similar-segments-clustering)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you work on the *pairwise* differences? Consider the values 1, 2, 101, 102, 201, 202. Pairwise differences are 1,100,101,200,201,99,100,199,200,1,100,101,99,100,1

The values of ~200 bear no information. There is a different "cluster" inbetween. You shouldn't use them for your analysis.

Instead, grab a statistics textbook and look up [Kernel Density Estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation). Don't bother to look for clustering - these methods are usually designed for the *multivariate* case. Your data is 1 dimensional. It can be *sorted* (it probably already is), and this can be exploited for better results.

There are well-established heuristics for density estimation on such data, and you can *split your data* on local minimum density (or simply at a low density threshold). This is much simpler, yet robust and reliable. You don't need to set a paramter such as k for k-means. There are cases where k-means is a good choice - it has origins in signal detection, where it was known that there are k=10 different signal frequencies. Today, it is mostly used for multidimensional data.

See also:

- [Cluster one-dimensional data optimally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869609/cluster-one-dimensional-data-optimally)
- [1D Number Array Clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513484/1d-number-array-clustering)
- [partitioning an float array into similar segments (clustering)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479944/partitioning-an-float-array-into-similar-segments-clustering?lq=1)
- [What clustering algorithm to use on 1-d data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147466/what-clustering-algorithm-to-use-on-1-d-data?lq=1)